# Ajax to PHP back to Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This might be a bit vague, but I'll do my best to summarize.

What I'm trying to do is get the value of a select element on change, store that result into a variable, then send it via Ajax to a php file called product_final.php.  At which point the PHP script will run through the database and pull the database results based on that variable and submit it back to the form so that it can be changed dynamically without the page being reloaded.

Again, a bit vague, but any help will be greatly appreciated. (Here's the code with a simple echo statement in the PHP file where I'm stuck at just trying to echo out the variable sent by Ajax.

```
jQuery("#field_6_17 select").on('change', function() {

  var productValue = jQuery(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../product_final.php",
        data: {productValue: productValue},
        cache: false,
        success: function(productFinal) {

        console.log("Sample of Product:", productValue);
    }
    });
    });
```

Here's the PHP trying to echo out the variable (The product_final.php file is blank and does not result in anything currently)

```
$finalProduct = $_GET['productValue'];
  echo $finalProduct;
```

Comment: should be `$_POST` not `$_GET`

Comment: I'd also suggest you look in to returning JSON from the PHP. It's more reliable than just returning text, which can have inconsistencies due to whitespace

Comment: You should use $finalProduct = $_POST['productValue']; because the method ajax is post

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value using `$_POST` method.  Updates code as below.

```
 $finalProduct = $_POST['productValue'];
 echo $finalProduct;
```

Comment: Whoops, had forgotten to update that.  Even after changing it to POST method nothing is returned via the product_final.php file.  Am I wrong in thinking that if the page is pulled up that the variable will appear without page reload?

Comment: No need to page refresh. If your request is going on product_final.php page. You must get the $_POST['productValue'] . Please check and confirm the value is going in ajax request.

Comment: The success: function(productFinal) is correctly console logging the selected result, it's just not showing on the PHP end even after setting the method to POST

Comment: You are getting productFinal value in after success. It means your response is right. Now where are you checking PHP code?

Comment: I'm using another file called product_final.php to execute the echo statement and setting the variable. The only two lines of code in that are the ones that I've put in the original question

Comment: you can not get the variable values by hitting directly product_final.php.

Comment: In ajax response , you will get the value from the product_final.php page

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding how to output the set the variable and then output it into the page without refresh. Could you maybe provide a code example?